# RBF-SVM prediction in python from sklearn training

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I trained a classifier with sklearn's SVC.fit(), and now I have the trained model. I can use the predict() method to predict the classes, but I want to implement it in python now. (I'm working on something where I need to be able to compute the gradients of the SVM. A working python implementation is the first step.)

For example, using the following code I can train an SVM model:

```
import sklearn.svm
import numpy as np

svm = sklearn.svm.SVC(probability=True, gamma=1)
f = svm.fit([[-3, -2], [0, 1], [.5,.5], [2, 1]], [0, 1, 0, 1])
```

And then compute a bunch of predictions along a line:

```
ar = np.arange(-5,6,.01)
r = [f.predict_proba([[i, i]])[0,0] for i in ar]
```

Now I try to implement a RBF-SVM method in python and compute the predictions that way:

```
A = 1; B = 0; C = 1;
def pred(vectors, coefs, x):
    dists = np.sum((vectors-x)**2,axis=1)
    probs = (np.exp(-dists*A+B))+C
    probs *= np.reshape(coefs,[-1])
    probs /= np.sum(np.abs(probs))
    return np.sum(probs)+.5

s = [pred(svm.support_vectors_, svm.dual_coef_, [i, i]) for i in ar]
```

And when I plot it, I get the following plot

[image: plot of sklearn svm.predict vs python predict]

It looks *mostly* correct, but everything isn't lining up perfectly. Why not? What is wrong with my implementation? (Also: why are there some flat regions randomly? Is sklearn rounding to 0.5 randomly?) I tried gradient descent over the possible values of (A,B,C) and found the best occurs at (A = 1.13; B = 0.31; C =   .88;) but this isn't all that enlightening.

I've tried looking through the sklearn source, but that just calls directly into a libsvm binary so I don't know what is happening there.

Comment: Wouldn't it be overfitting if it matched the blue line perfectly?

Comment: Well, it should match the line exactly, because I'm extracting exactly the model parameters...